# Would it be proper to state "I countermand you to...."?

Tags: grammar, word-usage, american-english

As in,

`He commanded you to go to hills.  But I countermand you to go to the hills.`
(to convey the "go to the hills" order being revoked/overridden)

I know the use of countermand in this context is awkward, but grammatically, is it correct? Or perhaps I should ask -- does the second sentence "make sense," even if it's unconventional usage of the word "countermand"?

Comment: *Forbid* would be correct.  *Countermand* is not because, as you seem already to be aware, its direct object is either the order itself or its speaker, not the recipient or the topic of the order.

Comment: @BenVoigt I see - thank you. Do you mind giving an example of a sentence where countermand's direct object is its speaker?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This isn't quite right as you are countermanding the command(order), not the person.

> He commanded you to go to hills.  But I countermand **that order** to go to the hills [and command you to stay here]

Comment: That's a shame. But it makes sense. Thank you.